# Problems uploading files to Google Drive with iOS

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have finally managed to get the Google Drive API working with iOS, using Swift.

I can access my Google Drive, and download folder and filenames, so I know the basic authentication and API is working.

The problem is when I try to upload a small file - and this error is generated

```
reason: 'unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission"}]},"id":"gtl_7"}'
```

I have set up what looks like a valid OAuth 2.0 client ID, but when I first tried this I had the wrong authorisation scope set up (from the example I copied) - 'kGTLAuthScopeDriveReadonly'.  I have now changed that to 'kGTLAuthScopeDrive', but I'm worried that the app may still be using the original scope as I cannot force a new login.

Here's the code I'm using to check that I'm logged in

```
func checkAuthorisation()
{
if let auth = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName(
    kKeychainItemName,
    clientID: kClientID,
    clientSecret: kClientSecret)
    {
        service.authorizer = auth
    }
    else
    {
        presentViewController(
            createAuthController(),
            animated: true,
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}
```

and here's my upload code

```
let metaData = GTLDriveFile()
metaData.title = "testfile.DAT"

let dataGoogleDrive = strMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
let uploadParamaters = GTLUploadParameters(data: dataGoogleDrive!, MIMEType: "text/plain")
let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesInsertWithObject(metaData, uploadParameters: uploadParamaters)

let serviceTicket = dataModel.googleDrive.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler:
    {(ticket, file, error) -> Void in
        print("complete")
    })
```

I have found a lot of posts describing the difficulties in getting Google Drive APIs set up, but that's no longer the issue.

1. is the problem simply that I'm still using cached credentials with the wrong scope? and if so, how do I flush that?
2. Is there something that I need to configure in the Google Developer Console?  There is an option to configure the Drive API to 'Allow users to create new documents using this application.' but when I try to use that, it will not allow me to save changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try going into Google Accounts and revoking that app's permission. It should then re prompt with the new scope

Comment: that sorted it completely.